# Автосмена картинок

Tags: jquery, javascript

Делаю автоматическую смену картинок через определенные промежутки времени. В данный момент код выглядит так:

```
var active = 0;
    var currElement = $('.menu').find('li').find('a');

    var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
        if(active != 3) 
            active++;
        else {
            active = 0;
        }
        currElement[active].click(); // красивый эффект для смены картинки
    }, 8000);
```

Проблема в том, что каждый раз, когда картинка меняется, браузер автоматически скроллится к блоку, где происходит эффект. Мне нужно, чтобы этого не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы на Вашем месте не придумывал новое, а взял хорошо заюзаное старое  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html

Зачем придумывать что то когда оно уже есть???

Comment: Как-бы конечно я согласен что велосипеды строить нехорошо. Но надо понимать схему работы такого рода вещей чтобы быть готовым к не шаблонным но похожим задачам.

Comment: >Писать что-то своё стоит только в 3-ех случаях:

> - Вы учитесь(лабораторная, курсовая)
- Вы пишете серьёзную научную работу именно на эту тему
- Вы наизусть знаете коды STL, Boost, десятка аналогичных библиотек, 3 томика Кнута и четко уверены, что решения для Вашего случая в них нет.

[Очнитесь, на дворе XXI век](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117193/)